# Xamarin Picker binding

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, picker

Am I missing something or is there more to it that I am not getting?  I'm working on a mobile app and have to use pickers for choices from a data table.  To start, I have many such pickers that are key/value based.  I have an internal ID and a corresponding Show value.  The IDs do not always have 1, 2, 3 values such as originating from a lookup table and may have things as

```
KeyID / ShowValue
27 = Another Thing
55 = Many More
12 = Some Item
```

Retrieved as simple as

```
select * from LookupTable where Category = 'demo'
```

So I have this class below that is used for binding the picker via a *list* of records

```
public class CboIntKeyValue
{
    public int KeyID { get; set; } = 0;
    public string ShowValue { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Now, the data record that I am trying to bind to has only the ID column associated to the lookup.  Without getting buried into [XAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language), but in general, I have my ViewModel.  On that I have an instance of my data record that has the ID column.

```
public class MyViewModel : BindableObject
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        // Sample to pre-load list of records from data server of KVP
        PickerChoices = GetDataFromServerForDemo( "select * from LookupTable where Category = 'demo'" );


        ShowThisRecord = new MyDataRec();
        // for grins, I am setting the value that SHOULD be defaulted
        // in picker.  In this case, ID = 12 = "Some Item" from above
        ShowThisRecord.MyID = 12;
    }

    // this is the record that has the "ID" column I am trying to bind to
    public MyDataRec ShowThisRecord {get; set;}

    // The picker is bound to this list of possible choices
    public List<CboIntKeyValue> PickerChoices {get; set;}
}
```

I can’t bind to the *index* of the list, because that would give me 0, 1, 2, when I would be expecting the corresponding "ID" to be the basis of proper record within the list.

In WPF, I have in the past, been able to declare the *show* value for the screen, but also the *bind value* to the ID column in similar.  So, the binding of the INT property on my "ShowThisRecord" would drive and properly refresh.

I can see the binding of SelectedItem, but that is the whole item of the KVP class which is *not* part of the MyDataRec.  Only the ID is the common element between them.

What is the proper bindings to get this to work?

```xml
<Picker ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ShowValue}"
   SelectedItem="{Binding ???}" />
```

Just to confirm my record bindings are legitimate, my page has binding context to MyViewModel as I can properly see the ID via a sample text entry I added to the page via.

```xml
<Entry Text="{Binding Path=ShowThisRecord.MyID}"/>
```

Comment: I believe that SelectedItem needs to be an item that is in the picker's ItemSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much work, I ended up writing my own separate class and template style for what I needed.  Due to the length of it, and posting the source code for anyone to use, review, assess, whatever, I posted that out [on The Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5266341/Xamarin-Picker-with-ID-based-Binding).

Again, the primary issue I had is if I have an integer key ID coming from a data source, the picker would not automatically refresh itself by just the given ID (int or string).

Answer (score 1):

I created a demo to test your code, and it works properly. The full demo is [here](https://github.com/jessiezh0320/IntBindingDemo). I also added a function to verify the selected item.

If you want to get the `SelectedItem` object synchronously, the MyViewModel should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and I created a  `selectedRecord`field for `SelectedItem`, so you can do like this:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        // Sample to pre-load list of records from data server of KVP
        //PickerChoices = GetDataFromServerForDemo("select * from LookupTable where Category = 'demo'");
        PickerChoices = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>() {
            new TestModel{MyID = 5, ShowValue="test1"}, new TestModel{MyID = 9, ShowValue="test2"},
            new TestModel{MyID = 18, ShowValue="test18"}, new TestModel{MyID = 34, ShowValue="test4"}
        };
        // Set the default selected item
        // foreach (TestModel model in PickerChoices) {
        //     if (model.MyID == 18) { // Default value
        //         SelectedRecord = model;
        //         break;
        //     }
        // }

        ShowThisRecord = new TestModel();
        // For grins, I am setting the value that SHOULD be defaulted
        // in picker.  In this case, ID = 12 = "Some Item" from above
        ShowThisRecord.MyID = 12;
    }

    // This is the record that has the "ID" column I am trying to bind to
    public TestModel ShowThisRecord { get; set; }

    //*****************************************

    TestModel selectedRecord; // Selected item object
    public TestModel SelectedRecord
    {
        get { return selectedRecord; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedRecord != value)
            {
                selectedRecord = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    //*****************************************

    // The picker is bound to this list of possible choices
    public ObservableCollection<TestModel> PickerChoices { get; set; }
}
```

class `ViewModelBase`

```
 public  class ViewModelBase: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And the XAML content:

```
 <Picker Title="Select a value" x:Name="mypicker"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path= PickerChoices}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRecord}"
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding MyID}"/>
```

File *xaml.cs*:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    ObservableCollection<TestModel> items = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>();
    MyViewModel testModel = null;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        testModel = new MyViewModel();
        BindingContext = testModel;

        // This will also work
        //if (testModel!=null && testModel.PickerChoices!=null) {
        //  for (int index=0; index< testModel.PickerChoices.Count; index++) {
        //      TestModel temp = testModel.PickerChoices[index];
        //      if (18 == temp.MyID) {
        //          mypicker.SelectedIndex = index;
        //          break;
        //      }
        //  }
        //}

        foreach (TestModel model in testModel.PickerChoices)
        {
            if (model.MyID == 18)
            { // Default value
                testModel.SelectedRecord = model;
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    // To show the selected item
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (testModel.SelectedRecord!=null) {
            DisplayAlert("Alert", "selected Item  MyID: " + testModel.SelectedRecord.MyID + "<--> ShowValue: " + testModel.SelectedRecord.ShowValue, "OK");
        }
    }

}
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the offer, but my issue is I want to DISPLAY the SHOW Value, but have it return the integer key.

Comment: It doesn't matter, whether it's a string or an integer, the binding is the same. replace code `ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding MyID}"` with `ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ShowValue}"`.

Comment: I have updated the answer and post the full demo I  tested, you can check it.

Comment: That looks very promising.  The last part to my problem is having the default show when screen starts.  Change your ID values to non-sequential, something like 5, 9, 18, 34 and set the default to 18.  Does the initial screen START with 18's "Show Value".  And the kicker is the list is built separately from the view model, so you don't know the list items directly to work with.  But since the record is coming from a table where the "ID" was already populated, we know that the ID is good.  I do appreciate your efforts in trying to help me resolve my issue.

Comment: Then you can filter the datalist at first. I have updated the answer , you can check it

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the ItemsSource property to your list of CboIntValue items:

```
<Picker Title="Select a value"
        ItemsSource="{Binding PickerChoices}"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ShowValue}" />
```

Comment: You need to set SelectedItem="{Binding ShowThisRecord.Value}" /> but you can't use ID because it's a Picker, you need to have the String value bound, so in your code first do ShowThisRecord.Value = PickerChoices.Single(p => p.Id == 12);